# TFSA withdrawl to make room for options deposit

Tags: canada, tfsa

If I stand to make $30,000 in capital gains on stock options that I hope to cash out in 2 years time, is it better to make room in my TFSA account by withdrawing TFSA funds the year before to make room for the stock option capital gains when I sell them and transfer them into a TFSA?

Comment: Making a capital gain in a normal account and transferring it to Tfsa does not provide a tax benefit. However if you make the gain within a Tfsa account to start with, then you save on taxes. If you want to transfer the gain, transfer it to an rrsp.

Comment: Oh ok, I was wondering that!  That makes sense.